# Creating FIFO in UNIX

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fifo

i`m trying to write simple FIFO program with three child proceses which send value to file and parent read this . My problem is that  cfp = fopen(fifoName,"w"); should earse file and save new value so i think otput should look like "This is the parent. Received value 30 from child on fifo "" but my output is "This is the parent. Received value 2010 from child on fifo " . Thanks for help.

What is wrong in my code?

```
int main()
{
  int ret;
  int p1, p2, p3, p4;
  int value;
  char fifoName[] = "/tmp/testfifo20";
  char errMsg[1000];
  FILE *cfp;
  FILE *pfp;
  int x1;
  int x2, x3, x4;

  ret = mknod(fifoName, S_IFIFO | 0600, 0);
  if (ret < 0)
  {
    sprintf(errMsg, "Unable to create fifo: %s", fifoName);
    errexit(errMsg);
  }

  if ((p3 = fork()) == 0)
  {
    x1 = 10;
    cfp = fopen(fifoName, "w");
    if (cfp == NULL)
      errexit("Unable to open fifo for writing");
    ret = fprintf(cfp, "%d", x1);
    fflush(cfp);
    exit(0);
  }

  if ((p2 = fork()) == 0)
  {
    x2 = 20;
    cfp = fopen(fifoName, "w");
    if (cfp == NULL)
      errexit("Unable to open fifo for writing");
    ret = fprintf(cfp, "%d", x2);
    fflush(cfp);
    exit(0);
  }

  if ((p3 = fork()) == 0)
  {
    x3 = 30;
    cfp = fopen(fifoName, "w");
    if (cfp == NULL)
      errexit("Unable to open fifo for writing");
    ret = fprintf(cfp, "%d", x3);
    fflush(cfp);
    exit(0);
  }
  else
  {
    pfp = fopen(fifoName, "r");
    if (pfp == NULL)
      errexit("Unable to open fifo for reading");
    ret = fscanf(pfp, "%d", &value);
    if (ret < 0)
      errexit("Error reading from named pipe");
    fclose(pfp);
    printf("This is the parent. Received value %d from child on fifo \n",
        value);
    unlink(fifoName);
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: "*i`m trying to write simple FIFO program with three child proceses which send value to file and parent*" Simple?

Comment: I'm wondering about the downvotes. A very interesting problem, with code, with expected and actual output. The code is even well written, with all sorts of error checking. I'm at a loss...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect `30`? You should expect any combination of `10`, `20` and `30`, like `102030` or `3020` or `20` or `2010`.

`2010` is a perfectly reasonable result. You fork 3 children. Actually there is a typo at the 1st fork, as you store its PID into `p3` instead of `p1`. But it does not matter.

What matters is that the scheduling of the parent process and its 3 children is not in your hands. Apparently the kernel scheduled your processes in the following order:

- p2 : wrote `20` into the FIFO
- p1 : wrote `10` into the FIFO, which contains `2010` now
- parent: read `2010` from the FIFO, which is empty now
- p3 : wrote `30` into the FIFO, which contains `30` now

But the parent process only reads the FIFO once, so it missed the `30`.